# C++ custom lazy iterator

Tags: c++, iterator

I have a somewhat simple text file parser. The text I parse is split into blocks denoted by `{ block data }`.

My parser has a `string read()` function, which gets tokens back, such that in the example above the first token is `{` followed by `block` followed by `data` followed by `}`.

To make things less repetitive, I want to write a generator-like iterator that will allow me to write something similar to this JavaScript code:

```
* readBlock() {
    this.read(); // {

    let token = this.read();

    while (token !== '}') {
        yield token;

        token = this.read();
    }
}
```

which in turn allows me to use simple for-of syntax:

```
for (let token of parser.readBlock()) {
    // block
    // data
}
```

For C++ I would like something similar:

```
for (string token : reader.read_block())
{
    // block
    // data
}
```

I googled around to see if this can be done with an iterator, but I couldn't figure if I can have a lazy iterator like this which has no defined beginning or end. That is, its beginning is the current position of the reader (an integer offset into a vector of characters), and its end is when the token `}` is found.
I don't need to construct arbitrary iterators, or to iterate in reverse, or to see if two iterators are equal, since it's purely to make linear iteration less repetitive.

Currently every time I want to read a block, I need to re-write the following:

```
stream.skip(); // {
while ((token = stream.read()) != "}")
{
    // block
    // data
}
```

This becomes very messy, especially when I have blocks inside blocks. To support blocks inside blocks, the iterators would have to all reference the same reader's offset, such that an inner block will advance the offset, and the outer block will re-start iterating (after the inner is finished) from that advanced offset.

Is this possible to achieve in C++?

Comment: Yes, it's very much possible. All you need is to make an iterator-like wrapper for your file parser. `begin()`, `end()`, `operator++`, `operator*` and `operator==` should be enough.

Comment: How would that work with the fact I don't know when I reach the end until it is reached?

Comment: Isn't that how all iteration work? You loop until you reach the end, then you stop. So when your parser reach } that would be equivalent of the `end()` iterator.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In order to be usable in a for-range loop, a class has to have member functions begin() and end() which return iterators.

What is an iterator? Any object fulfilling a set of requirements. There are several kind of iterators, depending on which operations allow you. I suggest to implement an input iterator, which is the simplest: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/InputIterator

```
class Stream
{
public:
    std::string read() { /**/ }
    bool valid() const { /* return true while more tokens are available */ }
};

class FileParser
{
    std::string current_;
    Stream* stream_;
public:
    class iterator
    {
        FileParser* obj_;
    public:
        using value_type = std::string;
        using reference = const std::string&;
        using pointer = const std::string*;
        using iterator_category = std::input_iterator_tag;
        iterator(FileParser* obj=nullptr): obj_ {obj} {}
        reference operator*() const { return obj_->current_; }
        iterator& operator++() { increment(); return *this; }
        iterator operator++(int) { increment(); return *this; }
        bool operator==(iterator rhs) const { return obj_ == rhs.obj_; }
        bool operator!=(iterator rhs) const { return !(rhs==*this); }
    protected:
        void increment()
        {
            obj_->next();
            if (!obj_->valid())
                obj_ = nullptr;
        }
    };


    FileParser(Stream& stream): stream_ {&stream} {};
    iterator begin() { return iterator{this}; }
    iterator end() { return iterator{}; }
    void next() { current_ = stream_->read(); }
    bool valid() const { return stream_->valid(); }
};
```

So your end-of-file iterator is represented by an iterator pointing to no object.

Then you can use it like this:

```
int main()
{
    Stream s; // Initialize it as needed
    FileParser parser {s};
    for (const std::string& token: parser)
    {
        std::cout << token << std::endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you! that allowed me to add the exact signature I wanted with a simple stream.read_block() call in a for loop :)

Comment: Mostly out of curiosity, because this code doesn't need to be particularly fast, but  do you know whether it will reduce performance noticeably compared to manually writing the block reading code above?

Comment: Just to follow up, it seems to be about 20% slower using the iterator, from my own test cases. Perhaps too much of a tradeoff for nicer syntax. Still very cool.

Comment: Hmmm, I wasn't expecting to be so much slower. What test did you did (which compile options did you use)? It would be interesting to know the reason behind that.